# PageIndexChange not getting handled after BindData

Tags: c#, gridview, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5, page-index-changed

Using `<asp:GridView` and `<asp:SqlDataSource`, I can `AllowPaging="True"` in the GridView and paging gets added and works perfectly.

However, if I use `<asp:GridView` but then don't use the `<asp:SqlDataSource`, instead if I use the C# coding method and create a `BindData()` function, everything works fine except when I try to actually use the paging.

I get the error:

```
The GridView 'GridView1' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled.
```

Why does this get handeled automatically when `<asp:SqlDataSource` and `AllowPaging="True"` are used together, but it doesn't get handled when `<asp:SqlDataSource` and `BindData()` are used together?